# About curse of dimensionality

Tags: database, image-processing, similarity, dimensions

My question is about this topic I've been reading about a bit. Basically my understanding is that in higher dimensions all points end up being very close to each other.

The doubt I have is whether this means that calculating distances the usual way (euclidean for instance) is valid or not. If it were still valid, this would mean that when comparing vectors in high dimensions, the two most similar wouldn't differ much from a third one even when this third one could be completely unrelated.

Is this correct? Then in this case, how would you be able to tell whether you have a match or not?

Comment: Can you cite some references?

Comment: Hi Marcelo,
Sure. I've been reading a bit about clustering from "Programming Collective Intelligence" and also some referenced papers. Note I'm not saying these sources state what I wrote in my post. I'm simply trying to get some basic understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically the distance measurement is still correct, however, it becomes meaningless when you have "real world" data, which is noisy.

The effect we talk about here is that a high distance between two points in one dimension gets quickly overshadowed by small distances in all the other dimensions. That's why in the end, all points somewhat end up with the same distance. There exists a good illustration for this:

Say we want to classify data based on their value in each dimension. We just say we divide each dimension once (which has a range of 0..1). Values in [0, 0.5) are positive, values in [0.5, 1] are negative. With this rule, in 3 dimensions, 12.5% of the space are covered. In 5 dimensions, it is only 3.1%. In 10 dimensions, it is less than 0.1%.

So in each dimension we still allow half of the overall value range! Which is quite much. But all of it ends up in 0.1% of the total space -- the differences between these data points are huge in each dimension, but negligible over the whole space.

You can go further and say in each dimension you cut only 10% of the range. So you allow values in [0, 0.9). You still end up with less than 35% of the whole space covered in 10 dimensions. In 50 dimensions, it is 0.5%. So you see, wide ranges of data in each dimension are crammed into a very small portion of your search space.

That's why you need dimensionality reduction, where you basically disregard differences on less informative axes.

Comment: dimensionaltiy reduction does not give you a magnitude when in high dimensional space (eg. processing 1000 dimensional features vectors for nearest neighbor search in multimedia retrieval)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple explanation in layman terms.

I tried to illustrate this with a simple illustration shown below.

[image]

Suppose you have some data features x1 and x2 (you can assume they are blood pressure and blood sugar levels) and you want to perform K-nearest neighbor classification. If we plot the data in 2D, we can easily see that the data nicely group together, each point has some close neighbors that we can use for our calculations.

Now let's say we decide to consider a new third feature x3 (say age) for our analysis. 
Case (b) shows a situation where all of our previous data comes from people the same age. You can see that they are all located at the same level along the age (x3) axis.
Now we can quickly see that if we want to consider age for our classification, there is a lot of empty space along the age(x3) axis.

The data that we currently have only over a single level for the age. What happens if we want to make a prediction for someone that has a different age(red dot)? 
As you can see there are not enough data points close this point to calculate the distance and find some neighbors. So, If we want to have good predictions with this new third feature, we have to go and gather more data from people of different ages to fill the empty space along the age axis.

(C) It is essentially showing the same concept. Here assume our initial data, were gathered from people of different ages. (i.e we did not care about the age in our previous 2 feature classification task and might have assumed that this feature does not have an effect on our classification).

In this case , assume our 2D data come from people of different ages ( third feature). Now, what happens to our relatively closely located 2d data, if we plot them in 3D? If we plot them in 3D, we can see that now they are more distant from each other,(more sparse) in our new higher dimension space(3D). As a result, finding the neighbors becomes harder since we don't have enough data for different values along our new third feature.

You can imagine that as we add more dimensions the data become more and more apart. (In other words, we need more and more data if you want to avoid having sparsity in our data)